# How can I Make a Steganographic Image

Tags: image, editor, steganography

I want to make a steganographic image using some very simple software.  I want to demonstrate the principle by opening up a bitmap image file in an editor that will let me see the binary that encodes the colours of individual pixels. I want to change the last couple of bits for some pixels to hide my secret binary message, then re-save the image.  I have seen that there are a few applications available that can create steganographic images, some of which are free, but they seem to hide what is really going on.  I want to see and edit the 'raw' binary for myself.  I hoped something like Notepad++ or Cyberchef would let me do this, but apparently not. Can you suggest something I can use please?

Comment: So what you're saying is that you want to see the raw data of an image and modify them *manually*. Exactly how does Notepad++ not allow you to do this? On another note, this question sounds awfully like asking for recommendations for off-site resources.

Comment: I cannot see how to do it in Notepad++  Can you tell me which options to select please?